# How to change the default UI for all Java Client applications?

Tags: java, swing

Since I have moved to a Linux (Fedora) laptop, all my Java based Client applications use a black background with white fonts. For example, with VisualVM:

[image]

Is there a way to set up, at JVM level, to use a different set of colors (f.e. white background)? Otherwise I have to edit on every Java tool the UI settings....
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. I've found it's inherited from the OS Themes.
I've changed the default Theme from my Fedora Menu. Now it works